# How to deploy a react application on a static server

Tags: reactjs, octobercms

I have a react application build with create-react-app. Its using octoberCMS as the backend fetching data using Axios calls from the frontend. Till now I was developing keeping the build content of react inside a directory named 'react' in the root directory of octoberCMS installation. Hence the URL I was hitting was http://example.com/react/.

The problem is now I am done with the development phase and look forward to deployment. But I want my front-end to be served at http://example.com and backend to be served at http://example.com/backend (backend served as I want). How can I achieve this? I am fairly new to both frameworks.

I have tried keeping the build content along with the rest of the octoberCMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First build your react app that will give you `vendor.js`[third party scripts] and your `app.js`[your actual app]

put them in to theme directory `assets` something

Then In Ocotber CMS make page with URL `/:url?` and paste your `index.html` content there.
it will be your `root` div and `including js` html, change path for `js` which points to the build js which you put in theme directory.

now what happens when anybody come to site
- we are serving same content as we do in dev build
- index.html with root tag and needed js

Now if use hit any other url like `https://www.example.com/test/etc` it also will be catch by `/:url?` (and all other requests) and home page served and our react app will work as we needed.

if any questions please comment.

Comment: Thanks for the support buddy but I was in a kind of hurry and moved my backend to a subdomain.

Comment: sure, may be next time :)